# Hosting a UserControl inside a custom DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a custom `DataGridViewCell` to show a specific `UserControl` when the user starts editing the cell. Basically the control contains a `TextBox` with a suggestion list easily handled by the code.
I got my code to resize the list correctly, and have it contain exactly what I want and where I want it. The problem I have now is that the control is not being drawn correctly on the screen, and the `ListBox` is probably beind drawn "inside" the row, and since it is much higher than the row, does not get shown on screen.

How can I make the control draw on top of the DataGridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to put the ListBox in a separate popup form.  Good luck.

Alternatively, you can put the ListBox in the GridView's parent form, then call `BringToTop` to make sure it's on top of the grid view.

Answer (score 1):

There's a msdn article, [Build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881%28VS.80%29.aspx#winf_numericup_topic2), that paints custom controls on datagridviews. The code sample provided there might help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to take a look at [Faking alternative controls within a DataGridView control in Win Forms 2.0](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/gary_farr/archive/2007/01/15/2605.aspx). It will ***look*** like the control is hosted within the DataGridView, but in actuality it is just positioned nicely over the cell. I am using this now for two DateTimePickers and one ComboBox with great success.

Sample code from link:

```
protected void dgCategory_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

{

//set Date Picker to false when initially click on cell

      if (dtPicker.Visible)
          dtPicker.Visible = false;
      if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
      {
      //set date picker for category datagrid
         dtPicker.Size = dgCategory.CurrentCell.Size;
         dtPicker.Top = dgCategory.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Top;
         dtPicker.Left = dgCategory.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Left;

         if (!(object.Equals(Convert.ToString(dgCategory.CurrentCell.Value), "")))
             dtPicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dgCategory.CurrentCell.Value);
         dtPicker.Visible = true;

      }
}

private void dtPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      dgCategory.CurrentCell.Value = dtPicker.Value;
      dtPicker.Visible = false;

}
```